# Test concrete method of an abstract class containing an interface call

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class:

```
public abstract class Foo{
  @Inject
  private FooBarClient foobarclient;

  public abstract long dofoo1();
  public abstract long dofoo2();

  public void doBar1(){
    foobarClient.docall(faa);
  }

}
```

I'd like to test the doBar1() method so I made my test class like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

private Foo foo;

@Mock
private FoobarClient foobarClient;

@Before
public void init() {
    foo = new Foo() {
        dofoo1(){};
    };
}

@Test
public void testControleValiditeSite() throws Exception {
    // G
    Response response=....;
    Mockito.when(foobarClient.docall(Mockito.any(faa.class))).thenReturn(
            response);
    // W
    foo.doBar1();
    // T;
}
```

But I got a null pointer exception on the fooBarclient in doBar1().

I also tried to mock the abstract with:

```
Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo,Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
```

Is there a better method to do this test?

**EDIT :**

I used reflection. Now the code looks like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

private Foo foo;

@Mock
private FoobarClient mockedFoobarClient;

@Before
public void init() {
    foo = new Foo() {
        dofoo1(){};
    };
    **MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);**
    **ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo , "foobarClient", mockedFoobarClient);**
}

@Test
public void testControleValiditeSite() throws Exception {
    // G
    Response response=....;
    Mockito.when(foobarClient.docall(Mockito.any(faa.class))).thenReturn(
            response);
    // W
    foo.doBar1();
    // T;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test class, create a non-abstract inner class that extends `Foo`. Use that in your test.

Comment: Hello, my problem is on the intarface call. Not in the abstract.
regards,

Comment: How are you setting `foobarclient` in the `foo` instance you created? I don't think the `Mockito` runner with support the `@Inject` annotation. Either set it explicitly or use `@InjectMocks`

Comment: I modified `code` @Mock
private FoobarClient foobarClient; to @InjectMock. And i call the implementation instead of the interface but now the Mockito.when(....) don't match. regards,

Comment: @InjectMocks would be an annotation on `foo` not `FooBarClient`. I suggest just doing `foo.foobarclient = foobarclient;` or call a setter method.

Comment: Use Spring's ReflectionTestUtils to set it.

Comment: Reflection was my last option .... but at least that worked ! I edit my first post. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to mock it, just create an instance in your test (assuming you're able to change the access type of client from `private` to `protected`).

```
Foo foo = new Foo() {
    @Override
    public long dofoo1() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long dofoo2() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setClient(FooBarClient client) {
        foobarclient = client;
    }
};

foo.setClient(client);
foo.doBar1();
```

Comment: Hello,
Unfortunatelly i can't use a set() :/

Comment: Can you change the access type to protected rather than private for the client?